# Does Next.js 13 cache data fetched from route handlers?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I need to fetch data from the client side, so I'm using a route handler as suggested in the official documentation. My question is: does Next.js 13 cache data fetched from route handlers so that the server doesn't fetch the same data every time the API is called?

Code example:

```js
export async function GET() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/users');
  const users = await response.json();

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(users));
}
```

I'm calling this route handler from the client side like this:

```js
const users = await fetch('/api/users');
const jsonData = await users.json();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the current Next.js V13 docs state that `fetch()` itself caches by default. The fact that it is used in the route handler of the server should not impact this.

> Caching stores data so it doesn't need to be re-fetched from your data
> source on every request.
>
> By default, Next.js automatically caches the returned values of `fetch`
> in the Data Cache on the server. This means that the data can be
> fetched at build time or request time, cached, and reused on each data
> request.
>
> ````js
> // 'force-cache' is the default, and can be omitted
> fetch('https://...', { cache: 'force-cache' }) ```
> ````

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data

Comment: Question: what happens if the bearer token changes? Will it use the old data? Should we manually clear the cache?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you could post your own separate question and see if others can answer that.

Comment: Notice (!) the following note from the same documentation: _fetch requests that use the POST method are also automatically cached. Unless it's inside a Route Handler that uses the POST method, then it will not be cached._

Answer (score 0):

There are different answers according to the documentation.  The first answer is NO:

> In Route handlers, fetch requests are not memoized as Route Handlers
> are not part of the React component tree.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch

The second answer is MAYBE:

> Opting out of Data Caching
>
> fetch requests are not cached if:
>
> - The cache: 'no-store' is added to fetch requests.
> - The revalidate: 0 option is added to individual fetch requests.
> - The fetch request is inside a Router Handler that uses the POST method.
> - The fetch request comes after the usage of headers or cookies.
> - The const dynamic = 'force-dynamic' route segment option is used.
> - The fetchCache route segment option is configured to skip cache by default.
> - The fetch request uses Authorization or Cookie headers and there's an uncached request above it in the component tree.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#opting-out-of-data-caching

The client side fetch to '/api/users', however, should be cached.